# Problem in changing paper size in tufte-book

Tags: margins, geometry, paper-size, tufte-book

I am using a `tufte-book` class. I printed some pages from my pdf document, and I noticed a wider space above and below the text, than the one I see when I display the pdf on a reader. I think this happens because the pdf is B4-sized, while I want to print my document on A4 paper.

I tried specifying the size of my paper in `\documentclass` options, but it was of no consequence. I tried specifying it in `\newgeometry` options, both as `paperwidth=210mm` and `paperheight=297mm`, and as `a4paper`, but again the pdf keeps being compiled in a B4 format.

Here is my preamble code, if you need it.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,symmetric,openany,nobib]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{geometry, sectsty, graphicx, array, multirow, amsmath, xfrac, upgreek}

\newgeometry{paperwidth=210mm, paperheight=297mm, top=24mm, bottom=20mm, right=30mm, left=18mm, marginparwidth=15mm, marginparsep=4mm}
\setlength{\headheight}{14.0pt}


% section titles
\allsectionsfont{\sffamily}
\sectionfont{\noindent\fontsize{14}{15}\textsf}

% tables
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.35}

% itemize
\setlength\itemsep{-20mm}

% mnotes
\newcommand{\mnote}[1]{\marginnote[18pt]{\footnotesize{\textsf{#1}}}}

% blank page
\newcommand{\intblank}{\newpage \thispagestyle{plain} \mbox{}}

% meta
\title{}
\author{}
```

Comment: First, use \geometry instead of \newgeometry.  IIRC, \newgeometry ignores changes in paper size.

Comment: That was it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As John Kormylo answered, the problem was in the `\newgeometry` command, which ignores changes in paper size. Using `\geometry` instead solved it.